# Problems with data types in flex

Tags: types, yacc, lex

I have a problem.

I'm writing a program with flex and I'm using this code:

```
%union {

    int entero;

    char *cadena;

    TipoDato tipo;

}
```

This code is for my data types.

I want evaluate the next line: expresion SUM expresion where SUM is the operation sum for evaluate, for example 69 + 60

When I write this

```
if (($1.tipo == ENT) && ($3.tipo == ENT)){

           $$.tipo = ENT;

} else if (($1.tipo == CADEN) && ($3.tipo == CADEN)) {

     $$.tipo = CADEN;

     } else {

          printf ("Error en la suma: Tipos de datos incompatibles Revise los tipos\n");

          yyerror(parser);

}
```

I have the next error

../src/buggy.y:350.37-38: $1 de `expresion' no tiene tipo declarado

../src/buggy.y:351.28-29: $1 de `expresion' no tiene tipo declarado

buggy.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:

buggy.tab.c:1646: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’

../src/buggy.y: At top level:

lex.yy.c:1577: warning: ‘yyunput’ defined but not used

lex.yy.c:1618: **warning: ‘input’ defined but not used

Leyendo fichero '../docs/prog1.bgy'.

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Bye!!

Answer (score 5):

These are all actually warnings, not errors, so your code should work despite them, but they are annoying.  To get rid of the bison warnings, you need to use a `%type` declaration in the top section of your .y file.  Somethings like `%type <tipo> expression`, and then you just refer to `$1` and `$3` and `$$` in your action code (no `.tipo` suffix, which is automatically supplied by bison due to the `%type`).

To get rid of the compiler warning in buggy.tab.c, you need to declare yylex in your .y file; something like:

```
%{
extern int yylex();
%}
```

in the top section, assuming you don't #define YYLEX_PARAM

Getting rid of the compiler warnings from lex.yy.c is harder; your best bet is probably just to NOT use -Wall when compiling it, as the code generated by flex is not -Wall clean

**edit**

after some searching, it seems you can get rid of the warning about input by putting a `#define YY_NO_INPUT` in the top section of your .l file.

Comment: flex has special instructions to avoid the unused definitions:

`%option noinput`

`%option nounput`